# vscode radian does not run the code sometimes

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am using VSCode for R programming for quite some time now. Recently, I decided to switch the vanilla terminal to radian. The highlighting and intellisense all work perfect. However, I am sometimes encountering a strange bug when sending code to the console.

So for instance sometimes when I highlight some line in the editor and hit ctrl+enter or run an entire .rmd chunk, the code does not get executed. The code does get copied to the console, but it's somehow buggy. Often, the console cursor hovers at some wrong bracket and one would have to move the cursor to the end in order to run the code.

Sometimes it's fully buggy displaying: [image] at the end of the console code.

Any ideas as to why this may be the case? It's pretty annoying.

Comment: I have been encountering this exact problem with both radian and the vanilla terminal in VSCode
So if anyone knows why this is happening it would be appreciated!

Comment: Also have the same problem!

Comment: Try to enable the "Bracketed Paste" on R extension for VSCode

Comment: @franzbischoff unfortunately, that does not solve the issue.

Comment: What is your VSCode version?

Answer (score 3):

Try adding `options(radian.auto_match = FALSE)` to your [radian profile](https://github.com/randy3k/radian#settings).

If you don't already have a radian profile, the most straightforward approach way to make one is to create a file called `.radian_profile` in the working directory. You can check your working directory by running `getwd()` in radian when it starts up.

In the `.radian_profile` file you created, paste this line:

```r
options(radian.auto_match = FALSE)
```

Comment: Could you provide more detailed instructions on where and how to add that line to our radian profile? For example, the link you provide offers numerous options such as `%USERPROFILE%/radian/profile` for Windows and then again `%USERPROFILE%/.radian_profile` for Windows. But it just assumes we know what those paths are, how to access them, and how to add options to them.

Comment: @coip I edited in instructions for what I see as the simplest method of creating a radian profile, which has the advantages of being platform independent and not requiring knowledge of environment variables.

Comment: I have same problem. I really think radian and vscode are great and tried many times to solve this error, but it still doesn't work. I also could not understand you answer about adding that to the radian profile. More detailed instructions are need for me too because I am not familar with programming. For example, where should I input %USERPROFILE%/.radian_profile or open it? Thank you very much. @andycraig

Comment: Hi @lijiaqi, you don't need `%USERPROFILE%`. Can you try the steps from 'If you don't already have a radian profile ...'? If you get stuck, please write which parts you were able to do successfully and which sentence you are stuck on.

Comment: Dear  
@andycraig. First, I want to explain my background. I use R in Windows system, and most time I use Rstudio and have no experience in C, python or other programming language expect R.  Before your comment, I read your instructions in Github, and tried to find the location (%USERPROFILE%/radian/profile). I do not sure what is it and surmise it located in the C:\Users\(my pc name). But I did not find the folder and file (radian folder and "profile").

Comment: According to your comment, I need to create a file called in the working directory. First, I do not know where is the working directory (sorry for my poor knowledge). I surmise a working directory is a folder in my pc (for example, a folder in C:\ ). I know folder in C:\ professional programmer often uses CMD or other terminal in Vscode to open folder in the Windows Explorer, but I do not know how to do that. Second, I  surmise "create a file" means ro creat a file like .txt. I do not sure whether my surmise is right or not. Or .radian_profile is a suffix?(like ”profile.radian_profile”?).

Comment: So, my problem is that (1), where is the the working directory and how can I find it. (2),  what type file should I creat. Is it a .txt file in folder in the Windows Explorer?(creat a .txt file and change its suffix to .radian_profile?). I know my problem may due to my poor knowledge. It will be very kind if you could give me some easy-to-understand explanation. Thank you very much.

Comment: You can check your working directory by running `getwd()` in radian when it starts up. It's probably the directory where your .R files are. Create a text file and rename it to `.radian_profile`. That's the whole file name, not a suffix.

Comment: doesn't work for radian still doesn't attach to vscode