# Radian Console adds random Characters as executed

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

I am facing a problem on a Windows PC using a Radian console for R.
When I execute a line, random characters are added to the end of the line in the console.
As you can see in the image attached, there is a ") added at the end of the line when I try to execute it.

Random Characters added Image

[image: 1]

Can somebody help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this is probably one of the issues descriped at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71410887/vscode-radian-does-not-run-the-code-sometimes Try the answer I posted there.